# can I use my CPU as a GPU

Tags: kernel, kvm-virtualization

I want to deactivate my Grafiks cart to give it a VM and I want to use my CPU to boot in to the GUI to start the VM and then to use the  GPU in a KVM supervist guest

So my question is can I get some driver that supports CPU graphical processing

I have an ryzen 5 3600 (no integrated GPU)
Thomahowk 450B motherboard 
Ubuntu 19 ( not afraid of switch)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe.

As you said, the AMD Ryzen 5 3600 has no integrated GPU, so you can't rely on it.

You may be able to login using Wayland instead of x.org.

Also, if your PC has an NVIDIA graphics card, you can install the corresponding video driver for use with x.org.

Many thanks to [karel](https://askubuntu.com/users/94914/karel) for her kind assistance.

Comment: Because the AMD Ryzen 5 3600 has no integrated GPU, computers that have an Nvidia graphics card will not be able to login to the desktop environment except with Wayland unless the proprietary graphics driver is installed.

Comment: I know I could use my GPU and I have the driver the problem is that I want to use a VM that gets the GPU. is there a way to get an video driver for the CPU?